# cakephp validation response returning data to controller

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

Hi i have made a custom validation in the model. How can i access the result($visitor) from this in the controller?

model:

```
<?php  
class Visitors extends AppModel 
{ 
    var $name = 'Visitors'; 

    var $validate = array(
        'xxx' => array(
            'rule' => array('checkxxx'),
            'message' => 'yyy.'
        )
    );

    function checkIxxx($check){
        $visitor = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => $check));
        return $visitor;
    }

}
```

?>

in my controller i want this:

```
function start() {  
        $this->Visitors->set($this->data);      
        if($this->Visitors->validates()) 
        {  
          if($this->Visitors->xxx->type == 'value') //this is a value from the $visitor array in the model**
          {
               //do something
          }

        }
```

is this possible?

Comment: sounds to me like you should be doing that in the model, aim is to keep as little code in the controllers as possible (fat models, skinny controllers).

Answer (score 1):

Updated to be a relevant answer, apologies.

```
//Model
var myField = 'invalid';

function myValidation($var){
  if($var === true){
    // Passed your validation test
    $this->myField = 'valid';
  }else{
    $this->myField = 'invalid';
  }
}

// Controller
$this->Model->set($this->data);
$this->Model->validates($this->data);

if($this->Model->myfield == 'valid'){
  // Field has passed validation
}
```

---

You will want to use

```
$this->Model->invalidFields()
```

Comment: i am looking for the data that comes through when it validates successfully

Comment: Well there isn't any that I know of. Have you tried setting a variable in your models validate function and then looking for it in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

PS: You dont follow cake conventions

the model should be "Visitor" (singular)